# button not work in IE11

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-11

Problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/7ZDbB/1/

If I click the first and second row's deny button,
the third row's deny button can't click just in IE 11.

I tested on IE8、IE9、IE10、Firefox and Chrome, and not this problem.

This is source code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="ja" lang="ja">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <style>
     #main table{ border-collapse:collapse; width:100%; }
     #main td{ border:1px solid #EEA; padding:4px 6px; }
     #main table tr.excepted td{ background:#F99;  }
     form table {background:#FEFEF1}
  </style>
  <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body >
  <div id="base">
     <div id="main">
        <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="" method="post">
           <input id="product_ids" name="product_ids" type="hidden">
           <table>
              <thead>
                 <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>name</th>
                    <th>product info</th>
                 </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                 <tr id="a_tr1_d_1084">
                    <td colspan="2">
                       <input type="button" value="allow" id="adAllowd_1084"  style="display: none;">
                       <input type="button" value="deny" id="adExceptd_1084" onclick="onDenyBtnClicked(&#39;d_1084&#39;)">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                       <table>
                          <tbody>
                             <tr>
                                <th>header1</th>
                                <th>header2</th>
                                <th>header3</th>
                             </tr>
                          </tbody>
                          <tbody>
                             <tr>
                                <td>subheader1</td>
                                <td>subheader2</td>
                                <td rowspan="2">
                                   other info
                                </td>
                             </tr>
                             <tr>
                                <td colspan="2">
                                   image
                                </td>
                             </tr>
                          </tbody>
                       </table>
                    </td>
                 </tr>
              </tbody>
              <thead>
                 <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>name</th>
                    <th>product info</th>
                 </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                 <tr id="a_tr1_d_1085">
                    <td colspan="2">
                       <input type="button" value="allow" id="adAllowd_1085"  style="display: none;">
                       <input type="button" value="deny" id="adExceptd_1085" onclick="onDenyBtnClicked(&#39;d_1085&#39;)">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                       <table>
                          <tbody>
                             <tr>
                                <th>header1</th>
                                <th>header2</th>
                                <th>header3</th>
                             </tr>
                          </tbody>
                          <tbody>
                             <tr>
                                <td>subheader1</td>
                                <td>subheader2</td>
                                <td rowspan="2">
                                   other info
                                </td>
                             </tr>
                             <tr>
                                <td colspan="2">
                                   image
                                </td>
                             </tr>
                          </tbody>
                       </table>
                    </td>
                 </tr>
              </tbody>
              <thead>
                 <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>name</th>
                    <th>product info</th>
                 </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                 <tr id="a_tr1_d_1090">
                    <td colspan="2">
                       <input type="button" value="allow" id="adAllowd_1090"  style="display: none;">
                       <input type="button" value="deny" id="adExceptd_1090" onclick="onDenyBtnClicked(&#39;d_1090&#39;)">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                       <table>
                          <tbody>
                             <tr>
                                <th>header1</th>
                                <th>header2</th>
                                <th>header3</th>
                             </tr>
                          </tbody>
                          <tbody>
                             <tr>
                                <td>subheader1</td>
                                <td>subheader2</td>
                                <td rowspan="2">
                                   other info
                                </td>
                             </tr>
                             <tr>
                                <td colspan="2">
                                   image
                                </td>
                             </tr>
                          </tbody>
                       </table>
                    </td>
                 </tr>
              </tbody>
           </table>
           <div id="allowAdSubmitButton"><input  name="commit" type="submit" value="submit button"></div>
        </form>
<script type="text/javascript">
   var $j = jQuery;

   function onDenyBtnClicked(adId) {

    $j('#a_tr1_'+adId).addClass('excepted');

    $j("#adAllow" + adId).show();
    $j("#adExcept" + adId).hide();

    $j("#product_ids").val(adId);
   }
   // -->
</script>
     </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I solved this problem by adjust javascript code order,like this

```
$j('#a_tr1_'+adId).addClass('excepted');
$j("#adAllow" + adId).show();
$j("#adExcept" + adId).hide();
```

↓

```
$j("#adAllow" + adId).show();
$j("#adExcept" + adId).hide();
$j('#a_tr1_'+adId).addClass('excepted');
```

But I really don't know the reason, because I change any of follow 11 points , the problem can be solved.

- delete table border-collapse style

  ```css
  #main table{ border-collapse:collapse; width:100%; }
  ```
- delete td border style

  ```css
  #main td{ border:1px solid #EEA; padding:4px 6px; }
  ```
- delete td background style

  ```css
  #main table tr.excepted td{ background:#F99;  }
  ```
- delete table backgroud style

  ```css
  form table {background:#FEFEF1}
  ```
- delete submit button
- delete javascript code that add 'excepted' css to tr

  ```
  $j('#a_tr1_'+adId).addClass('excepted');
  ```
- delete javascript code that show allow button and hide deny button

  ```
  $j("#adAllow" + adId).show();
  $j("#adExcept" + adId).hide();
  ```
- delete javascript code that set value to 'product_ids'

  ```
  $j("#product_ids").val(adId);
  ```
- delete first `colspan` attribute on per row
- delete first `rowspan` attribute on per row
- delete second `colspan` attribute on per row

I'm quite puzzled and really don't get what is causing the problem. I'm hoping someone can help me, thank you.

Comment: Please include a link to the problem on plunkr ir jsfiddle and try in different browsers to see if it is an IE only problem

Comment: @JasonGoemaat Sorry, I forgot to write this."I tested on IE8、IE9、IE10、Firefox and Chrome,and not this problem."

Answer (score 0):

This is an odd issue for sure. **It appears to be a bad painting issue in IE 11 that prevents interacting with the page.**

Take notice that after you click 2 deny buttons (order does not matter) the hover states of all the allow/deny buttons go away. Then click down and drag off of the submit button, and viola - all of the buttons (and text) are now interactive again.

Applying some best-practices to your code coincidentally fixes this issue as well. If you are using jQuery - you should not be using inline onclick attributes. A main goal of jQuery is to separate behavior from content. A better way to bind your click events would be to add a class to your deny and allow buttons then bind the click to them or to their closest static parent (in case your rows are being dynamically added). Also, since you're already toggling a class on the nearest parent, you may as well use that class to show/hide the correct button.

New JS:

```
$(function() {
    $('#main').on('click', '.button-deny', function() {
        $(this).closest('tr').addClass('excepted');
        $("#product_ids").val($(this).data('ad-id'));
    });
});
```

Additional CSS:

```
.excepted .button-deny,
.button-allow { display:none; }
.excepted .button-allow { display:inline-block; }
```

Relevant HTML Update:

```
<input type="button" value="allow" class="button-allow" data-ad-id="d_1084" />
<input type="button" value="deny" class="button-deny" data-ad-id="d_1084" />
```

And here's an updated fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/7ZDbB/6/

If I can pinpoint the specific painting issue that is causing this issue, I'll update this answer.

Comment: I changed td border to 5 and I found this.If click second row's button, right border of subheader2 not appeared.http://jsfiddle.net/7ZDbB/7/